# $_SERVER not set with command line -r option?

Tags: php, command-line

When I try to print the $_SERVER variable from a command line php, it thinks $_SERVER is not set.

```
$ php -r "print_r($_SERVER);"
Warning: print_r() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in Command line code on line 1
```

However, when it's in a file, running it from the command line has it set

```
$ cat test.php
<?
print_r($_SERVER);

$ php test.php
Array
(
    [TERM] => xterm
    [SHELL] => /bin/bash
    [SSH_CLIENT] => 192.168.1.101 49319 22
    [SSH_TTY] => /dev/pts/0
...
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the $ character on the command line.

```
php -r "print_r(\$_SERVER);"
```

Otherwise the shell will think it's a shell variable called _SERVER (which you don't have set to anything) and so what's actually been run is `php -r "print_r();"`, which is why you get the error "print_r() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given".

Comment: Thanks! Also, if I use single quotes in the argument, no need for escaping :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> You may or may not find any of the following elements in $_SERVER. Note that few, if any, of these will be available (or indeed have any meaning) if running PHP on the command line.